# Images don't resize consistently in different browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have created a website based on Chrome, without checking constantly the compatibility with IE and Firefox. The result is I have this problem in these two pages (please use Firefox or IE to see the issues and then Chrome to compare):

http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact.html

http://www.onsyzygy.com/Store.html

The first one ignores my limitation for the thumbnails, while the second one ignores the padding between them, it seems.

Here are the CSS and "Contact" and "Store" HTML files as a whole, since I don't know 
where exactly the problem is:

```css
.thumb {
 
  max-height: 75px;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.thumb1{
 
  max-height: 700px;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.thumb2{
 
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.thumb3{
 
  max-height: 85px;
  max-width: 310px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}



#navbar1
{
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap; 
 float: left; 
    list-style: none; 
    position: relative; 
    left: -1%; 
 right: -30%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
 background-color: white; 
 width: 140%;
 margin-top: -8px; 
 overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -22%;
}

#navbar2
{
 display: inline-block; 
 white-space: nowrap; 
 float: left;
    list-style: none; 
    position: relative; 
    left: -1%; 
 right: -30%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; 
 background-color: white; 
 width: 140%; 
 margin-top: -8px; 
 overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -22%;
}

#navbar3
{
 display: inline-block; 
 white-space: nowrap; 
 float: left; 
    list-style: none;
    position: relative; 
    left: -1%; 
 right: -30%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; 
 background-color: white; 
 width: 140%; 
 margin-top: -26px;
 overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -22%; 
}
 
.navbar li
{
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin-left: 0; 
    margin-right: 0;

}

.navbar a:link,a:visited
{
 display:block;
 width:130px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#999999;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
 background-color:#FFFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 padding:7px; 
 text-decoration:none; 
 text-transform: none;

}

.navbar a:hover,a:active
{
 background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000;
}

#bgcontainer 
{
    width: 175%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 
}

.st1 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
 position: relative;
}

.st2 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
 position: relative;
 }
 
.st3 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
 position: relative;

 }


.box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:-325px; 
    margin-top:-170px;  
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
 }


.box0{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-325px; 
    margin-top:-170px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.box1 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-478px; 
    margin-top:-170px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.box2 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-485px; 
    margin-top:-150px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.concept {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-325px; 
    margin-top: -335px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.comics {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-394px; 
    margin-top:-90px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.DI {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-324px; 
    margin-top: 110px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}


#thumbs
{
    width: 2000px;
}

#thumbs img
{
 display: inline;
 white-space: nowrap;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 position: center center;
}


html {
    width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position: relative;
}

body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><-->   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />   
<link href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Onsyzygy | Contact</title>

<div>
<ul id="navbar1" class="navbar">
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://onsyzygy.com/Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Blog">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Store.html">Store</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>

<style type="text/css">
p 
{ 
font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left;}
</style>
</head>

<body width="100%" class='wsite-theme-light' color="FFFFFF">

<div id="bgcontainer">
<style>
body
{
background-image: url('http://www.onsyzygy.com/Monogram background.jpg'); /* This is your background image */
background-size:1300px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: fixed;
background-position:center center;

}
</style>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<TABLE WIDTH="80" height="10" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="10" style="float: left; margin: 0px;">

<!-- <tr><th><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Connect1.jpg" width="70%"></th></tr><-->

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img class="thumb" WIDTH="285" height="75" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Social.png"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="mailto:gabriele.cuscino@gmail.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Gm.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Gm1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Gm.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr>  

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/onsyzygy" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Fb.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Fb1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Fb.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://twitter.com/GabrieleCuscino" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Tw.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Tw1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Tw.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://onsyzygy.deviantart.com/gallery/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Da.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Da1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Da.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr>  

<tr>
<td><a href="http://onsyzygy.tumblr.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Tb.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Tb1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Tb.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr>  
</table>

<TABLE WIDTH="50" height="20" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0" style="float: left; margin: 0px;">

<tr>
<td><img class="thumb1" WIDTH="50" height="700" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Divider1.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>


<TABLE WIDTH="30" height="40" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="10" style="float: left; margin: 0px;">

<tr>
<td><img class="thumb2" WIDTH="30" height="120" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Blank.png"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img class="thumb2" WIDTH="30" height="100" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Blank.png"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img class="thumb2" WIDTH="30" height="100" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Blank.png"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Download/Portfolio.pdf" download="Portfolio"><img  src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/GC.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/GC2.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/GC.png'"border="0" align="right" height="30%"></p></a></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><img class="thumb3" WIDTH="310" height="85" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Portfolio.png" align="right"></a></td>
</tr>

</body>   
</html>
```

```css
.thumb {
 
  max-height: 75px;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.thumb1{
 
  max-height: 700px;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.thumb2{
 
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.thumb3{
 
  max-height: 85px;
  max-width: 310px;
  max-width: 100%
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}



#navbar1
{
 display: inline-block; /* Displays it as a line, instead of a column; needed to eliminate the float element for the "nowrap" feature */
 white-space: nowrap; /* Eliminates the word wrap for the navbar */
 float: left; /* Needed to center */
    list-style: none; /* Needed to center */
    position: relative; /* Needed to center */
    left: -1%; /* Needed to center, -10% for compensanting */
 right: -30%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; /*adds a shadow*/
 /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; /* Adds the transparent background if no bg color is set */
 background-color: white; /* Adds the background color */
 width: 140%; /* Makes the background to be extended to the whole screen */
 margin-top: -8px; /* This moves the bar on the Y axis */
 overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -22%; /* these two lines are adding white spaces in the navbar textes, before and after - I've set this to center the navbar and it seems to work together with "right: -30%" */
}

#navbar2
{
 display: inline-block; /* Displays it as a line, instead of a column; needed to eliminate the float element for the "nowrap" feature */
 white-space: nowrap; /* Eliminates the word wrap for the navbar */
 float: left; /* Needed to center */
    list-style: none; /* Needed to center */
    position: relative; /* Needed to center */
    left: -1%; /* Needed to center, -10% for compensanting */
 right: -30%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; /*adds a shadow*/
 /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; /* Adds the transparent background if no bg color is set */
 background-color: white; /* Adds the background color */
 width: 140%; /* Makes the background to be extended to the whole screen */
 margin-top: -8px; /* This moves the bar on the Y axis */
 overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -22%; /* these two lines are adding white spaces in the navbar textes, before and after - I've set this to center the navbar and it seems to work together with "right: -30%" */
}

#navbar3
{
 display: inline-block; /* Displays it as a line, instead of a column; needed to eliminate the float element for the "nowrap" feature */
 white-space: nowrap; /* Eliminates the word wrap for the navbar */
 float: left; /* Needed to center */
    list-style: none; /* Needed to center */
    position: relative; /* Needed to center */
    left: -1%; /* Needed to center, -10% for compensanting */
 right: -30%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; /*adds a shadow*/
 /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000; /* Adds the transparent background if no bg color is set */
 background-color: white; /* Adds the background color */
 width: 140%; /* Makes the background to be extended to the whole screen */
 margin-top: -26px; /* This moves the bar on the Y axis */
 overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -22%; /* these two lines are adding white spaces in the navbar textes, before and after - I've set this to center the navbar and it seems to work together with "right: -30%" */
}
 
.navbar li
{
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin-left: 0; /* these two lines are adding white spaces in the navbar textes, before and after */
    margin-right: 0;

}

.navbar a:link,a:visited
{
 display:block;
 width:130px; /* spacing between the buttons */
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#999999;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
 background-color:#FFFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 padding:7px; /* this adds space between the top of the page and the navbar */
 text-decoration:none; /*this is to eliminate the underline in the links */
 text-transform: none;

}

.navbar a:hover,a:active
{
 background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000;
}

#bgcontainer 
{
    width: 175%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 
}

.st1 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
 position: relative;
}

.st2 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
 position: relative;
 }
 
.st3 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
 position: relative;

 }


.box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:-325px; 
    margin-top:-170px;  
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
 }


.box0{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-325px; 
    margin-top:-170px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.box1 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-478px; 
    margin-top:-170px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.box2 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-485px; 
    margin-top:-150px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.concept {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-325px; 
    margin-top: -335px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.comics {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-394px; 
    margin-top:-90px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}

.DI {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
 margin-left:-324px; 
    margin-top: 110px;  
 top:50%;
    left:50%;

}


#thumbs
{
    width: 2000px;
}

#thumbs img
{
 display: inline;
 white-space: nowrap;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 position: center center;
}


html {
    width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position: relative;
}

body {
    overflow-y: hidden; /* this pins the background and hide the scroll bar for the whole body */
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*.stretch 
    margin: auto; 
    height:100% */
}


/*#h2 { 
 font-size: 1.5em;
 background-color: #ccc;
 margin: 1em;
 padding: 3em;
} */ /*text format for "Gallery" thumbnails */
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />   
<link href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Onsyzygy | Store</title>

<div>
<ul id="navbar1" class="navbar">
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://onsyzygy.com/Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Blog">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Store.html">Store</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
p 
{ 
font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left;}
</style>
</head>

<body width="100%" class='  wsite-theme-light' color="FFFFFF">
<div id="bgcontainer">
<style>
body
{
background-image: url('http://www.onsyzygy.com/Section.jpg'); /* This is your background image */
background-size:1300px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: fixed;
background-position:center center;

}
</style>
</div>

<br>

<TABLE WIDTH="80" height="10" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="10" style="float: left; margin: 0px;">

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img WIDTH="285" height="75" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Prints.png"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.designbyhumans.com/shop/Onsyzygy/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Db.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Db1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Db.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.qwertee.com/profile/338039" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Qw.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Qw1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Qw.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://society6.com/GabrieleCuscino" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/s6.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/s61.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/s6.png'"border="0" align="left" height="30%"></p></a></td>
</tr></table>

<TABLE WIDTH="50" height="20" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0" style="float: left; margin: 0px;">

<tr>
<td><img height="500" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Divider1.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<TABLE WIDTH="30" height="40" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="10" style="float: left; margin: 0px;">

<tr>
<td><img WIDTH="30" height="120" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Blank.png"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img WIDTH="30" height="100" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Blank.png"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://form.jotformeu.com/form/43185775600356" target="_blank"><img  src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/GC.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/GC2.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/GC.png'"border="0" align="right" height="30%"></p></a></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><img WIDTH="310" height="85" src="http://www.onsyzygy.com/Contact/Links/Direct.png" align="right"></a></td>
</tr>

</table>


<br>

</div>

</body>   
</html>
```

Please, tell me if you need other media/info in case I did it wrong.

Comment: Please specify exactly what we should see in the renderings, i.e. what differences you are referring to. Explain this in terms of the renderings themselves. You should also try to reduce the problem to a simpler case, by removing features that probably don’t affect the issue.

Comment: You should view the console output in Internet Explorer and resolve markup issues. For instance, you have your navigation markup inside the `<head>`.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - Thanks, I'll do that! How I can trigger the console output in IE?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - If you'll open the two pages in Google Chrome, you'll see that all the icons are properly sized, while in Firefox and IE they are not resized, messing up the layout. I really cannot identify the problem but I can tell for sure that something is wrong in the resize feature in my HTML/CSS for that two browsers.